# printing for loop output in one line Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, line

I Have the code here which converts ASCII to Base 64, inputting "Cat" gives me the output 
The Base 64 is Q
The Base 64 is 2
The Base 64 is F
The Base 64 is 0

How can I make the output print on one line thus that "Cat" will give "The Base 64 is Q2F0"?

```
b64_table = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"
number = 0
numchar = 0
code = 0

user_input = input("Input")

for char in user_input:
    numchar = numchar + 1
    if numchar == 1:
        number = ord(char)
    elif numchar > 1:
        number = ord(char) + (number << 8)

    if numchar == 3:
        i=3
        for i in (3,2,1,0):
            code = number  >> (6 * i )

#print(int(code))
            print("Yout base64 is "+ b64_table[int(code)])

            number = number - (code  << (6 * i))
```

Comment: You could _append_ the pieces of the result to a string during the iteration and then output the final string at the end.

Comment: I really don't see why you don't use base64.encode.

Comment: @bconstanzo: I really don't see why people cannot try and learn how base64 works as they learn to code.

Answer (score 1):

Collect your base64 characters in a list first, then *join* them after the loop has completed and print your intro just once:

```
result = []
for i in (3,2,1,0):
    code = number  >> (6 * i )
    result.append(b64_table[int(code)]))
    number = number - (code  << (6 * i))

result = ''.join(result)
print("Your base64 is", result)
```

This is the more efficient method; the alternative slower method would be to use string concatenation, adding your base64 characters to a string `result`:

```
result = ''
for i in (3,2,1,0):
    code = number  >> (6 * i )
    result += b64_table[int(code)])
    number = number - (code  << (6 * i))

print("Your base64 is", result)
```